# My 401(K) plan and form 5500

Tags: united-states, income-tax, 401k, roth-401k

I live in the United States and have a small unincorporated business. I have no employees and I am single. I have a 401(K) and a Roth 401(K) through E*Trade. Between the two accounts I have a little over 200K in them.

I have not been filing form 5500 for these plans and I believe I do not have to. Do I?

I believe that when the balance in these plans reaches 250K, I do. Is that correct?

If you think I have to file the form, please comment on the following URLs from [employeefiduciary.com](https://www.employeefiduciary.com/blog/the-401k-form-5500-frequently-asked-questions-faq) and [nolo.com](https://www.nolo.com/legal-encyclopedia/the-rules-filing-irs-form-5500-your-solo-401k-plan.html)

However, if you look at the [Department of Labor's site](https://www.dol.gov/sites/dolgov/files/ebsa/employers-and-advisers/plan-administration-and-compliance/reporting-and-filing/form-5500/2018-instructions.pdf), you will see the following:

> Section 1: Who Must File
>
> A return/report must be filed every year for
>   every pension benefit plan, welfare benefit plan, and for every entity
>   that files as a DFE as specified below (pursuant to Code section 6058
>   and ERISA sections 104 and 4065).  If you are a small plan (generally
>   under 100 participants at the beginning of the plan year), you may be
>   eligible to file the Form 5500-SF instead of the Form 5500. For more
>   information, see the instructions to the Form 5500-SF.

What is a DFE?

Comment: Is this a _Solo_ 401(k) plan that is _administered_ by E*Trade or a regular 401(k) plan in which you are the employer, employee (and sole participant) as well as the plan administrator?  As I remember, there was a Form 5500-EZ (instead of the full-blown Form 5500) hat needed to be filed by plans with assets under 250K, or maybe by plans with just one participant.

Comment: This is a Solo 401(k) plan that is administered by E*Trade.

Comment: @Bob Is there anywhere that suggests you still need to file if your total balance is below $250k?

Comment: If you will just _read_ the contents of the first link that you have provided, you might just notice that the FAQ says that one-participant Solo 401(k) plans that have less than $250K in assets at the end of the calendar year need not file even Form 5500-EZ for that year, and when the assets grow above that limit, Form 5500-EZ must be filed, not the full-blown Form 5500 which is a _lot_ more paperwork.

Comment: @CraigW I have updated my post showing a reason why I might need to file Form 5500 or Form 5500-EZ.

Comment: @Bob In the bottom link, look under "Do Not File a Form 5500 for a Pension Benefit Plan That Is Any of the Following": "11. A 'one-participant plan,' as defined below. However, certain one-participant plans are required to file the Form 5500-EZ, Annual Return of One-Participant (Owners and Their Spouses) Retirement Plan with the IRS or may file the Form 5500-SF, Short Form Annual Return/Report of Employee Benefit Plan, electronically with EFAST2." Then the instructions for Form 5500-EZ will tell you not to file if plan assets are under $250k.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you don't have to file any Form 5500 unless it's the plan's final year.

In the [Form 5500 instructions](https://www.dol.gov/sites/dolgov/files/EBSA/employers-and-advisers/plan-administration-and-compliance/reporting-and-filing/form-5500/2019-instructions.pdf), under "Do Not File a Form 5500 for a Pension Benefit Plan That Is Any of the Following", it lists:

> 11. A “one-participant plan,” as defined below. However,
>       certain one-participant plans are required to file the Form
>       5500-EZ, Annual Return of A One-Participant
>       (Owners/Partners and Their Spouses) Retirement Plan or A
>       Foreign Plan, with the IRS or may file the Form 5500-SF,
>       Short Form Annual Return/Report of Employee Benefit Plan,
>       electronically with EFAST2.

In the [Form 5500-EZ instructions](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/i5500ez.pdf), under "Who Does Not Have To File Form
5500-EZ", it says:

> You do not have to file Form 5500-EZ for the 2018 plan
>   year for a one-participant plan if the total of the plan's
>   assets and the assets of all other one-participant plans
>   maintained by the employer at the end of the 2018 plan
>   year does not exceed $250,000, unless 2018 is the final
>   plan year of the plan.

Since your total balance is around $200k you are exempt.

The [Form 5500-SF instructions](https://www.dol.gov/sites/dolgov/files/EBSA/employers-and-advisers/plan-administration-and-compliance/reporting-and-filing/form-5500/2019-sf-instructions.pdf) also exempt "one-participant plans" from filing.